# required field not working for type button

Tags: html

is it possible to use **required** attribute with the button `type="button"` instead of `submit`?

```
<form id="form1" >
    <select required>
    <option value="">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="go">
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/td57gebj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Required is only for fields that must be filled with data. Buttons are used to trigger something, so it can't be set to required. If your form will be used to send data to your server then there is no reason not to use `submit`.